# Create a type to be used in the foreach loop. Java

Tags: java, foreach

Simply is it possible to create a type, in java, which can be passed into the foreach loop after the colon? And if so, how?

At first I thought I that foreach only worked for arrays, but then it came to my attention that `List`s could be iterated over. My question is then is this something that the interpreter does automatically or is it possible to create classes of my own which can be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just implement the `Iterable` interface.

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html:

> Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the "foreach" statement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. You have to implement the [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface and you can use it in the enhanced `for` loop.

As the documentation says:

> Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the "foreach" statement.

Answer (score 1):

To have this functionality you can implement [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface.  You need to implement your own `iterator()` method.  Then, you can use the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As it says in [the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), you need to implement the [`Iterable` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html). If you do, instances of your class can be used in an enhanced `for` loop.

`Iterable` is a very, very simple interface: It requires that you have an `iterator` method that returns an [`Iterator<T>` instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).